# Calculating activity score based on log in activity?

Tags: algorithms

I have a site where user logs in. I need to calculate the log-in activity score based on the age when he logged in. For example :-

1. If user logins today he will have high score than the user who logged in yesterday or sometime in past.
2. Similarly user who logged in this week will have high score than the user  who logged in  last week.
3. Another usecase can be user who logged in  for more days in a week should be considered more active .

I am running out
of ideas how to caluclate activity score based on above kind of rules ? Is there any solution available on google for the same(I did not
find any with my search)

Comment: Who calculates activity scores for their users? What are they used for?

Comment: 1+2 are the same rule in different words, and how you weight "time since last login" vs. 3 ("number of days / week") is up to you, we cannot decide this for you, it is totally arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a half-life based approach. For each user, keep an activity score and time of last activity (login). The current activity score is the stored value multiplied with 0.5^(activityAge/halfLife). When an activity occurs, you add 1 to the computed score, store it in the variable, and update the time of last activity. You may want to suppress counting multiple logins per day to avoid unreasonably high scores.

Comment: Can you please provide an example ? What is activityAge and halfLife  here ?

Comment: activityAge and halfLife are the time since last activity and the time after which an activity should count only half of its initial value. Which unit you use (seconds, days, or years) doesn't matter, as long as both are in the same unit. For example, a login exactly one day ago when the halfLife is 7 days would be worth 0.5^(1/7) = 0.90572366426391. Does that help?